# AWK if condition matching a string

Tags: linux, awk

I have the following awk command. I'm trying to find the error and print the first line from the error. If the error has a matching string, then i'm trying to add it in the count and later print the result in the END statement.

How do I use the if condition for the requirements I have with the below statement, plus print the number of occurrences of the error?

```
awk '/^SomeError[0-9]+/ {for(i=0;i<=3;i++){getline;if(i==0 && $1 ~ /PATTERN_TO_FIND/ ){print;count++;}}} END {print count;}' SomeLogfile.log.2015-07-06 | less
```

Today it print nothing if I use the if condition with the following regular expression. If I remove it from the command including he end statement, it prints the results, but i'd like to use this condition for counting purpose and print as well.

```
$1 ~ /PATTERN_TO_FIND/
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `for(i=0;i<=3;i++)`? You are only interested in the case where `i==0`?

Comment: @NathanWilson I'm still learning. I was printing first 3 lines earlier. Now I'm just interested in the first line.

Comment: Can you put a sample of the input file?  I assume that the the line containing the condition searched NOT in the same line as the actual error?

Answer (score 3):

If you have spaces in your PATTERN TO FIND, use $0 instead.
$0 ~ /PATTERN TO FIND/

Comment: Your answer will find the pattern in entire line and not just the first field which the OP wants(AFAIK from question).

Comment: That may actually be exactly what he wants, though this has nothing to do with spaces in the pattern.  $1 just means the first field (separated by the default delimiter (space).  In this case, it's the first field in the line occurring immediately after the matching SomeError line.

Comment: Try putting the code into a code-block [how do i format my code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 3):

This will print lines starting with `SomeError`, and increment the count if the first field of the first line also matches `PATTERN`:

```
awk '/^SomeError/ {print;if($1 ~ /PATTERN/){count++;}} END {print count;}' filename
```

If you want to count `PATTERN` anywhere on the first line, replace `$1` with `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

From what msr has answered, i was able to figure out the solution myself. the following command worked for me.

```
awk BEGIN {count=0;} '/^SomeError[0-9]+/ {getline;if($0 ~ /PATTERN_TO_MATCH/){print $0;count++} END {print count;}' SomeLogfile.log.2015-07-06
```

Comment: Were you trying to match the pattern over the entire line or just the first field. Also `for(i=0;i<1;i++)` doesn't make any sense. It would be better to remove the loop instead.

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish entire line actually, that was my novice mistake. Din knew the difference of $0 and $1. Now I know what they mean to me. If I remove the for loop, will it just take the first line?(looks like that to me from your comment)

Comment: Your loop will only make its content to run once since `i<1` condition won't be satisfied in the next iteration. Hence it would be same as not writing the for loop since in both case the `getline, if.....` will be executed once. Also you forgot to put closing brace of for loop.